# How to check if an integer array is sorted without using an "if" statement?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I change this code to work without using an if statement? I tried using a while loop and it wasn't working. I've since realised I was using the while loop incorrectly. How do I do it then? (Using java)

```
public class isSorted {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declaring array literal
        double a[] = {1.5, 4.3, 7.0, 19.5, 25.1, 46.2};
        int L = a.length;
        boolean isSorted = false;
        for (double i = 0; i < L; i++) {
            if (a[(int) i] < a[(int) (i + 1)]) {
                isSorted = true;

            }
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(isSorted);
    }

}
```

Comment: So to be clear, conditional statements or expressions are OK - just not an `if` statement ?  Btw - you have a `double` array - not an `integer` array.  Technically the result could be derived exclusively using `Arrays` methods.

Comment: Yeah conditional statements are alright, just not if statements.

Comment: What do you mean by Arrays methods? I'm very new to Java, or programming for that matter.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the ternary operator (`?`) instead of an `if`?

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you don't want to use an if-statement? (If this is for an assignment, it sounds odd that this is the only restriction.)

Comment: @deHaar we haven't studied those yet, so I don't think so.

Comment: @Ivar Yes, this is for an assignment for my intro to programming class. One part of it asked me to write a code to check if an array of doubles was sorted. Another part was to modify this code to write it without using an if statement.

Comment: OK, understand... It is *like* an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
double a[] = {1.5, 4.3, 7.0, 19.5, 25.1, 46.2};
int i = 0;
while (i < a.length - 1 && a[i] <= a[i + 1]) 
    i++;

boolean isSorted = i >= a.length - 1; 
System.out.println(isSorted);
```

Basically you check if the current element is less than or equal the next element until you find a mismatch or the whole array is parsed. then checking the value of the `i` variable will tell you if the array is sorted or not.

For checking descending order just change the condition to:

```
a[i - 1] >= a[i]
```